# Website URL using wrong DNS

Tags: domain-name-system

Why does my Google App domain, mail.theworldes.com, keep getting redirected to a storage.co.uk (run by giraffe.co.uk) with the url being http://www.mail.theworldes.com.  I can reach my main site with no issues.  We use Route53 and the CNAME record (mail.theworles.com/ghs.google.com) is set correctly.  It has happened to other colleagues and then does away as well.  On my computer I have cleared the DNS cache.  Run CC Cleaner and no issues.  I also have tried from my wife's laptop and my mobile phone and still get this crazy site page.  My DNS in my IPconfig is manually set to CenturyLink's (my ISP) main DNS servers.  So, it seems to be something is wrong with the DNS.  Please help.  This is getting very annoying issue.

Answer (score 1):

I receive a correct answer using `dig mail.theworldes.com`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.theworldes.com.    605 IN  CNAME   ghs.google.com.
ghs.google.com.     86104   IN  CNAME   ghs.l.google.com.
ghs.l.google.com.   300 IN  A   74.125.45.121
```

The URL answers correctly to ping with the IP above and reach a login page when opening with a browser. Maybe it was a delay in propagating the domain to DNS servers?

Comment: Well, it wasn't just a delay.  It clears up and then sometimes it is back, but it is always the same site from the storage.co.uk.  It happens to be fine now, but I can't figure out the root cause of the issue.  Sometimes it is only me that gets this redirect to happen, and sometimes it is only happening to my business partner who is using Comcast.  During this time no domain records have been changed.